# Why doesn't HTML printing page break work?

Tags: html, css, printing

I have a loop in my code that generates divs with content.

I'm trying to achieve a page break after each such div.

What I've tried:

```css
@media print {
  div {
    float: none !important;
  }
  .pagebreak {
    clear: both !important;
    display: block !important;
    page-break-after: always !important;
    break-after: page !important;
  }
}

@media all {
  .pagebreak {
    display: none;
  }
}

@page {
  width: 210mm;
  height: 297mm;
}
```

```html
<div class="pagebreak" style="page-break-after: always !important; break-after: page !important;">&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp;</div>
```

I know I have the style both inline and in the style file, but I was grasping at straws.

I've also tried using `page-break-before` with similar results.

Everything is ignored by both Firefox and Chrome. Is there a trick to make it work that I'm missing?

Comment: Your `.pagebreak` style in `@media all` is currently located **after** your `@media print` rule, so your `display: block;` property will be ignored. The ordering of CSS at-rules matters. Always put the most general rules (i.e. `@media all`) first.

Comment: Also, you really don't need to use `&nbsp;`. (and using it will break CSS's `:empty` pseudo-class).